# OpenMP Mac OSX Lion c++ linker error Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_omp_get_thread_num"

Tags: c++, osx-lion, openmp

I cannot find this question anywhere on the internet.
So my linker error is: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_omp_get_thread_num()"

This is my code:

```
int nthreads;
int tid;
#pragma omp parallel private(tid)
{
    tid = omp_get_thread_num();
    if (tid == 0) 
    {
        nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
        printf("number of threads: %d\n", nthreads);
    }
}
```

Comment: `-fopenmp` option both enables parsing of OpenMP pragmas at compile time and linking with `libgomp` OpenMP run-time library (and also with `libpthreads`) at link time. To help others diagnose your problem it would be nice to also show the command line which produces the error, not only the error. Mind that in your future questions.

Comment: If you're linking you'd want to use the -lgomp flag: `g++ -o "se710_a1" ./src/se710_a1.o -lgomp` So in Eclipse instead of adding libomp as the library, you would need to add gomp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks you forgot to use the `-fopenmp` flag to tell the compiler you want to use openmp, your example compiles fine as `g++ test.cpp -fopenmp -o test` on mac osx lion

Comment: Thanks for responding!  I am going to look at this page later tonight

Comment: You were the first one to answer, so I gave you the checkmark.  Both of you are correct.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to diagnose such a problem. I guess  the linker cannot find the library. Add libgomp to you linker libraries.

You have to link library, to get object.

Simular problem here:

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/901477/

and more more over the internet. Reason is not linked library.

you can do it by adding: `-fopenmp`

in GCC.

Comment: Thanks for responding!  I am going to look at this more closely tonight.

Comment: Yes, it is hard to diagnose a poorly described problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using OSX you should do following steps:

1. `brew install gcc`
2. `brew install libomp`
3. `g++-9 -fopenmp -o main main.cpp`
   (instead on '`9`' you should write your version of `gcc`)
4. run with `./main`

Comment: finally something that worked. `g++-11` instead of `gcc-11` was it for me, trying to execute a `*.cpp`